# Много пространства в блоке меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass, menu

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-p2f3c1ISgtYy16R2QtcXRYZTA HTML
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-p2f3c1ISgtbUlBeS1rZ0k1UlE CSS

Дело такое, замутил меню но появилась проблема, в блоке менюшки очень много спеса и ее можно прокручивать, что уже не очень, долго уже сижу и не могу понять в чем проблема, гляньте плиз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-p2f3c1ISgtdHN6RDdNdUQ3WlU

Comment: js еще на всякий

Comment: Сделайте нормальный пример в вопросе.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

В `body,html` убери overflow-x: hidden, а в `header` - overflow: hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/7r8ghj5u/1/